Necessary and sufficient conditions for a stabilizer code to have certain transversal gates
We have many sufficient conditions to judge if a stabilizer code has certain transversal gates. For example:

CSS codes will have block-wise transversal CNOTs.
self-dual codes will have transversal Hadamards $H$.
doubly even codes will have transversal phase gates $S$. (See this answer for more details about 1/2/3)
k-ply even codes will have transversal $R_Z(2\pi/2^k)$

Among the above three conditions, being a CSS code is also a necessary condition for having transversal CNOTs (see the proof from Adam here).
My question is: Are these conditions also a necessary condition to have certain transversal gates?
